# Creating a Tensor using a pre-populated pd dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, recommendation-engine

I am trying to create a item-item based collaborative filtering recommendation engine. Because of the large volume of data flowing through, I have had to use TensorFlow. However I even after spending hours on the documentation and on the internet, I am unable to figure out how to create a tensor using a pre-populated ndarray.

I am trying to transpose a ndarray with user item actions to record the information in a tensor. I have debugged multiple errors including shape mismatches only to find a new error I can't find any information around. Below is the code. Any help/suggestions is highly appreciated.

```
user_item_matrix = tf.Variable(np.zeros(shape = (num_usr,num_prd)),dtype=tf.int32)
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)
for index,row in user_item_action.iterrows():
    update_row = usr_ht[row['user_id']]
    update_col = prd_ht[row['product_id']]
# Updating row slices of the tensor
update = [0]*num_prd
update[update_col] = row['action_score']
user_item_matrix = sess.run(tf.scatter_add(user_item_matrix,update_row,np.transpose(update)))
sess.close()
```

TypeError: Input 'ref' of 'ScatterAdd' Op requires l-value input

user_item_action.head():
        user_id     product_id        action_score
1354    76864       196823            10
2626    23364       234437            10
6422     8055       231014            10
9877    81965       200476            10
13334   88132       240015            10

Comment: Why do you show `user_action_item.head()`, if you don't use this variable in the code? Is there a typo?

Comment: Corrected, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Do not assign result of `sess.run` to `user_item_matrix`. `sess.run` returns the **value** of the changed variable, and if you assign `user_item_matrix` a regular value, it will not be a TF variable anymore and you'll not be able to assign it anymore.

Comment: Hey Sygi, thanks for the insight. I had a hunch that this is the problem however I am not sure how to update the user_item_matrix then ? Seems to be a catch 22 situation. Can you kindly help me resolve this ?

Comment: `sess.run(scatter_add(user_item_matrix, ...` __does__ update the `user_item_matrix` variable.